"Cannot place order because a payment method was not provided" when using Stripe to programmatically place an order
I recently upgraded Magento from 2.3.4 to 2.4.6 and as a result updated stripe/stripe-payments from 2.9.5 to 3.4.0.
Previously I was able to set up a quote to place an order programmatically as follows:
const PAYMENT_METHOD = 'stripe_payments';
//...

$quote = $this->cartFactory->create();

//... other quote setup

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)->setShippingMethod(self::SHIPPING_METHOD);
$quote->setPaymentMethod(self::PAYMENT_METHOD);
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
$this->cartRepository->save($quote);

$customerId = (int)$customer->getId();
$stripeCustomer = $this->stripeCustomerRepository->getByMagentoCustomerId($customerId);
if (empty($stripeCustomer->getId())) {
    throw new BadPaymentException(__('Stripe customer is not found. Customer id: %1', $customerId));
}

$this->sessionQuote->setCustomerId($customerId);
$cards = $stripeCustomer->getCustomerCards() ?? [];
$savedCard = reset($cards);

if (!$savedCard) {
    throw new BadPaymentException(__('Saved card is not found. Customer id: %1', $customerId));
}
$savedCardData = $savedCard->id . ':' . $savedCard->brand . ':' . $savedCard->last4;

$quote->getPayment()->addData([
    'method'   => self::PAYMENT_METHOD,
    'cc_saved' => $savedCardData
]);

$this->cartRepository->save($quote);

However not when I place the order I get an error from Stripe:
[2024-10-05T22:51:10.249744+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException: Cannot place order because a payment method was not provided. in /vendor/stripe/module-payments/Helper/Generic.php:949
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/stripe/module-payments/Plugin/Sales/Model/Service/OrderService.php(57): StripeIntegration\Payments\Helper\Generic->dieWithError('Cannot place or...', Object(Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException))
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService->aroundPlace(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
#2 /vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/Sales/OrderManagement/AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin.php(166): Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
#3 /vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Plugin/Sales/OrderManagement/AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin.php(141): Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin->createOrder(Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor), Array, Object(Magento\InventorySales\Model\SalesChannel), Object(Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\Data\SalesEventExtension))
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\InventorySales\Plugin\Sales\OrderManagement\AppendReservationsAfterOrderPlacementPlugin->aroundPlace(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Interceptor))
...

I'm struggling to find any documentation.  Am I setting the payment method incorrectly?

Have you found any solution? I am facing same issue
